# Net::OpenSSH command remote with multi pipeline

Tags: bash, perl, perl-module

i have a problem when attempt run multi command in remote linux, with Perl and Module   Net::OpenSSH.                                               .

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $new_connect = Net::OpenSSH->new($D_CONNECT{'HOST'}, %OPT); 
my $file = "file.log.gz" 
my ($output2, $error2) = $new_connect->capture({ timeout => 10 }, "gunzip -c /path/to/file/$file | tail -n1 | awk '/successfully completed/ {print \$NF}'");
```

the output that i get is:

bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
bash: -c: line 1:` |tail -n1 |awk '/successfully completed/ {print $NF}''
;;;

any idea or suggestion, thanks.

Fcs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a quoting error. Just let Net::OpenSSH take care of the quoting for you:

```
my ($output2, $error2) = $new_connect->capture({ timeout => 10 },
                                               'gunzip', '-c', "/path/to/file/$file", \\'|',
                                               'tail', '-n1', \\'|',
                                               'awk', '/successfully completed/ {print $NF}');
```

Note how the pipes (`|`) are passed as a double reference so that they are passed unquoted to the remote shell. The module documentation has a section on quoting.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the error message you'd get if you had a newline at the end of your `$file` string, causing the pipe character to be at the start of a second line (interpreted as the start of a second command).

This test deomstrates the same error:

```
bash -c 'echo foo
           | cat'
```

So I guess your bug doesn't really occur with `$file = "file.log.gz"` and whatever your real `$file` is, you need to chomp it.

A bigger mystery is why bash says the error is on line 1 of the `-c`. ash, ksh, and zsh all correctly report it on line 2.